# Is there a working example of React Transition Group's SwitchTransition component?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I am trying to use a `SwitchTransition` component. Unfortunately, the [code in the docs](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition) is not a complete example and I'm having trouble filling in the blanks. Does anyone have a simple example of this component being used, such as a CSS fade-out then fade-in?

I can't find any examples online. Does this mean that there is another common approach that I'm overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made a simple example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-fast-xffvp) that uses SwitchTransition to transition the text being displayed.

The react-transition-group docs link to [vue transition modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) which give some insight into how the switch transition works.

Comment: I opened a PR to the repo to try and improve the documentation a while ago but there's no progress on it

Comment: PR was merged - [#585](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/pull/585)